Ubuntu 24.04 Failed to open PTY: Permission denied
I have got an issue with non-admin users on my Ubuntu 24.04 laptop. A have added a regular user and this user cannot open gnome-terminal. It shows an error
"There was an error creating the child process for this terminal. Failed to open PTY: Permission denied." Everything is OK for my admin user, from which I have added others.
My /dev/ptmx permissions:
ls -la /dev/pts/ptmx 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 2 дек 30 00:27 /dev/pts/ptmx

I have added this line to the /etc/fstab:
devpts           /dev/pts              devpts  gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=666  0 0

The regular user is added to the dialout group.
I have read suggestions from ChatGPT and this topic. Nothing helps! Please advise me with something.

"My /dev/ptmx permissions:" [...] "ls -la /dev/pts/ptmx"... /dev/ptmx and /dev/pts/ptmx are obviously not the same filenames.

"I have added this line to the /etc/fstab:" Don't! These virtual files are automatically managed by systemd or some similar low level component. I don't know what's broken but it needs to be located and fixed there, instead of looking for building up an operating system totally differently than its developers intended.

How did you create that new user? Using an "official" method provided by Ubuntu? If you create yet another user, does it work for them? Do other terminal emulators (e.g. xterm) start up?

I think the issue is more likely to be something specific to the non-admin user's gnome-terminal profile settings (perhaps an invalid custom command?). I don't have a gnome-based desktop at the moment but iirc you should be able to browse / reset properties via the dconf-editor utility.
